# PreviousPage Findcontrol Issue

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to get the text of the following linkbutton that is set to postback to another page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("computername") %>' PostBackUrl="~/assetdetails.aspx" CommandName="Select">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have tried many things in the receiving pages load event but this is what i ended up with:

```
Dim GV As GridView = TryCast(PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("content").FindControl("GridView2"), GridView)
Dim LB As LinkButton = TryCast(GV.SelectedRow.Cells(0).FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)
lblAsset.Text = LB.Text
```

Obviously it doesnt (returns blank, not null) work or i would not be making this post. :)
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong way.

Here GridView is inside a Content Page ( which uses a master page), so access the `GridView` present originally in content page as:

```
If (Not (Me.Page.PreviousPage) Is Nothing) Then
    Dim ContentPlaceHolder1 As Control =
                  Me.Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
    Dim GV As GridView =
                  CType(ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)

    Dim LB As LinkButton =
            TryCast(GV.SelectedRow.Cells(0).FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)
    lblAsset.Text = LB.Text
End If
```

GridView and other contents are present inside `ContentPlaceHolder` controls actually.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. The "content" in my code is the contentplaceholder. It finds any other columns text in the gridview except text in templatefields.